# Links do not work when the public folder name is underscore, e.g. public_html

Tags: php

Problem with links when the folder in the name contains the underscore "_". Why? and how to improve it, because my hosting of the main "public" folder is called "public_html" I changed the name of the directory and below in the code, but then the links do not work for to css and subpages. If I change the name to any other name without underlining, everything works. Unfortunately, I have to use "public_htnl"

```
<?php
  define("PRIVATE_PATH", dirname(__FILE__));
  define("PROJECT_PATH", dirname(PRIVATE_PATH));
  define("PUBLIC_PATH", PROJECT_PATH . '/public_html');
  define("SHARED_PATH", PRIVATE_PATH . '/shared');


  $public_end = strpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], '/public_html') + 7;
  $doc_root = substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], 0, $public_end);
  define("WWW_ROOT", $doc_root);

  require_once('functions.php');
?>
```

**functions.php**

```
<?php
function url_for($script_path) {
  // add the leading '/' if not present
  if($script_path[0] != '/') {
    $script_path = "/" . $script_path;
  }
  return WWW_ROOT . $script_path;
}
?>
```

**One of my links**

```
<a href="<?php echo url_for('/home/index.php'); ?>">Home</a>
```

Comment: It could depend upon the configuration of your HTTP server, e.g. Apache

Comment: I use the latest xampp for testing, what to look for in the configuration, what to change?

Comment: I suspect the `+7` in the definition of `$public_end` needs to be `+12` to match the change in length of the root directory name.

Comment: That's what it was about, thank you. And you can tell me how it is for production(hosting), because according to the recommendations I have to use "define (" WWW_ROOT ", '');" what all my theories crush me. 
How my code should look like on production (hosting)